# XML Address Trouble

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml that I want to insert some info, the code is working fine but when it comes to the address of the XML I'm having some trouble.

I have a link in other page with:

`produtoadicionado.php?page=adicionar&cod_produto=1&id=1&nome_produto=Arroz`

What I want is complete the name of the XML with the value of $id before. Which in this case is 1.

So it will call and add in: `1_produtos.xml`

But is not working. Is creating a new xml named `$id_produtos.xml`

**produtoadicionado.php**

```
<?php 
$page = $_GET["page"];
$cod_produto = $_GET["cod_produto"];
$id = $_GET["id"];
$nome = $_GET["nome_produto"];



    if ($page == 'adicionar')
    {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('$id_produtos.xml');
    $produto = $xml->addChild('produto');
    $produto->addChild('nome', $nome);
    $produto->addChild('cod', $cod_produto);
    file_put_contents('$id_produtos.xml', $xml->asXML());
}

?>
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
simplexml_load_file('$id_produtos.xml');
file_put_contents('$id_produtos.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

into this:

```
simplexml_load_file("{$id}_produtos.xml");
file_put_contents("{$id}_produtos.xml", $xml->asXML());
```

Please, note the use of double quote instead of the single quote which let PHP to interpret the vars name and replace that with their value. You can read more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: Ok i change this line and also:
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$id_produtos.xml");

But is giving me this:


Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity ".xml" in /home/ticoteco/public_html/produtoadicionado.php on line 14

Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in /home/ticoteco/public_html/produtoadicionado.php on line 15

Comment: the 14 line is: $xml = simplexml_load_file("$id_produtos.xml"); witch is correct.

Comment: and the 15 is: $produto = $xml->addChild('produto');

Comment: i only have this in my xml: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<produtos></produtos>

Comment: @user1044413 I found the real problem. Please, see the updated answer ;)